# Connection Refused when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, neo4j

Hi I am running out of idea why is this happening, I'm new with rspec. Please tell me what's wrong with this. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

**Here's the error and trace.**

> *1) Company should have fields named "name", "website", and "type" of
>   type String
>        ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mUnable to find matching line from backtrace←[0m
>        ←[31mErrno::ECONNREFUSED←[0m:
>          ←[31mNo connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)←[0m ←[36m*     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in
>   `initialize'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`
>   open'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block
>   in connect'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in`
>   timeout'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in
>   `timeout'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`
>   connect'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in
>   `do_start'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in`
>   start'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in
>   `request'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:93:in`
>   perform'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:521:in
>   `perform_request'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:473:in`
>   post'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:563:in
>   `post'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/neography-1.0.8/lib/neography/connection.rb:40:in`
>   post'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/neography-1.0.8/lib/neography/rest/gremlin.rb:18:in
>   `execute'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/neography-1.0.8/lib/neography/rest.rb:336:in`
>   execute_script'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/Workspace/comlinked_support/spec/spec_helper.rb:47:in `block (2
>   levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:i n`instance_exec'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:i n `instance_eval_with_args'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:622:in`
>   instance_eval_wit h_rescue'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in
>   `instance_eval_with_resc ue'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:31:in`
>   run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in
>   `block in run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in`
>   each'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in
>   `run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in`
>   run_hook'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:473:in
>   `run_after_each_ho oks'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:292:in`
>   run_after_each'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:123:in
>   `block in run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:248:in`
>   with_around_each_hooks' ←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in
>   `run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:515:in`
>   block in run_exam ples'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in
>   `map'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in`
>   run_examples'←[0m
>
> ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in
>   `run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in`
>   block (2 levels) in  run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in
>   `map'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in`
>   block in run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in
>   `report'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in`
>   run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in
>   `run'←[0m ←[36m     #
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in`
>   block in autorun'←[0m

**mongoid.yml**

```
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: comlinked_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'simplecov'

require 'simplecov-rcov'
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter

SimpleCov.start

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'  


require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expose_current_running_example_as :example
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.color = true
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  config.before(:suite) do
    Fabrication.clear_definitions
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    $neo_server.execute_script("g.clear()")
  end


  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view

  config.extend DeviseControllerSpecSupport, :type => :controller
  config.include DeviseRequestSpecSupport, :type => :feature

  config.include Mongoid::Matchers
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  Warden.test_reset!
end
```

**company_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Company do
  it { should have_fields(:name, :website, :type).of_type(String) }
end
```

**company.rb**

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid
  include Mongoid::Slug

  field :name, type: String
  field :website, type: String
  field :type, type: String
end
```

Comment: Did you run db:migrate in test environment?

Comment: Yup. Tried that, but still I'm getting that error